# Need to change transparency of an object once dialog with NPC completes

Tags: lua, roblox

I am new to Roblox scripting and I was trying to make a weapon change from transparent to visible once dialog starts with an NPC.

I set the transparency of the weapon "Autohyperlaser" to 1 in the properties so it is transparent by default.  I have an NPC called "Weapon_holder" that has a Dialog and DialogChoice child.  So the hierarchy is:

```
workspace.Weapon_holder.Head.Dialog.DialogChoice
```

I created a script underneath the DialogChoice object that has the following code:

```
local Dialog = script.Parent

Dialog.DialogChoiceSelected:Connect(function(Player, Choice)
workspace.Autohyperlaser.Handle.Transparency = 0
end)
```

I was expecting the transparency of `workspace.Autohyperlaser.Handle` to change from 1 to 0 after any dialog choice was chosen.  However, the gun remains transparent, so the script is either incorrect or not being called. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Is there any output/errors? Have you done any debugging (e.g., simple `print` statements inside your function) to know whether (1) your script is running and (2) the event is being fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DialogChoiceSelected](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/event/Dialog/DialogChoiceSelected) event can only be fired client-sided. It is an event of 
a [Dialog](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/Dialog), not [DialogChoice](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/DialogChoice). And you have to use it in a [LocalScript](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/LocalScript) since the event is client-sided only. You can either put the LocalScript into the character by putting it into the StarterPlayer>StarterCharacterScripts or into the player by putting it into the StarterPlayer>StarterPlayerScripts since LocalScripts will only run if it is a descendant of these or any other player descendant object.

For the code, you just have to change the Dialog variable:

```
local Dialog = workspace.Weapon_holder.Head.Dialog --Since it is an event of a Dialog

Dialog.DialogChoiceSelected:Connect(function(Player, Choice)
workspace.Autohyperlaser.Handle.Transparency = 0
end)
```

It should be fired now if the LocalScript is in the right place.